reflection of a cylindrical mirror



hello. The picture is from a perspective book I am reading. (The name of the book is The 'Complete Guide to Perspective Drawing From One-Point to Six-Point' by Craig Attebery)
The first figure (figure 31.1) was easy to understand. However, I don't understand the second picture (figure 31.2) and the following pictures.
What I mean is, in the first situation, a mirror with a flat surface, I can directly connect the observer's line of sight to the virtual object inside the mirror, so I can immediately find the point where it touches the reflective surface, and so I can directly find the Normal.
However, in the second picture, there is a reflection on a cylinder-shaped mirror.
How on earth can determine the point where the observer's (SP) line touches the reflecting surface? You might say that all you have to do is find the point where the normal touches the reflective surface, but then how on earth is the point where the normal touches the reflective surface determined?
Or did even measure each point on the surface where the angles of incidence and reflection between the SP and the actual object are symmetrical? Or is there some simple geometric method? Otherwise, I wouldn't be able to understand this picture at all.

The picture is not fitting on my mobile device screen. Can it be made mobile-friendly?

@OscarLanzi I want to do what you want, but I don't know how.

With regard to reflections, curved surfaces act as though they were actually made up of lots of little flat tiles. If the size of such flat tiles shrinks down to approach zero, the plane of each tile is called the tangent to the surface at that point. It is a well-known fact in geometry that the tangent to a (right circular) cylinder at a point $P$ is normal (perpendicular) to the line through $P$ that intersects the cylinder’s axis perpendicularly. That’s what the figure is illustrating.
If what you want is the point where the line $EV$ between the eye and the virtual image intersects the mirror’s surface, find the point $A_E$ along the cylinder’s axis such that segment $A_E E$ is the normal through the eye and the corresponding point $A_R$ for the real image, and compute their midpoint $A_M = \frac{A_E + A_R}{2}$. Then the point you want is the intersection of the cylinder with the bisector of $\angle E A_M R$.

Oh my... I don't understand these formulas with my current knowledge. Which subject of mathematics should I study to understand this? And what does the 'A' in the symbol you mentioned stand for?

You’ll have essentially no success understanding the kind of thing you’re asking about without studying geometry, and likely some basic algebra too. And I chose the letter A to suggest the word axis.

All right. But how much geometry and algebra should I learn? When I searched for the concept you mentioned, linear algebra came up. Should I study it this far?

One gentle yet very relevant place to start is Paul Lockhart’s book Measurement. By the way, it’s a great book to understand what mathematicians actually do, and where the creativity and beauty of math arise.

I search that and Someone is raving about that book. This is a book that I think will be helpful for learning perspective as well. I will definitely see it. thanks.

Before that, I kept reading this article and thinking about it. maybe Are you talking about the angle obtained by dividing the sum of the angle from the center of a circle towards the observer and the angle towards the actual object divided by 2? But in the last picture, the normal line doesn't seem to be exactly bisected from the center of the circle, so I guess it's not what I thought.
